# Kubernetes: PersistentVolume Validation Error and spec.persistentvolumesource: Forbidden: is immutable after creation

Tags: kubernetes, persistent-volumes

I'm trying to deploy ping devops on my local machine but get the following error message when I try to set up the server profiles:

error validating "lab05-local-profile-deploy.yaml": error validating data: ValidationError(PersistentVolume): unknown field "nodeAffinity" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.PersistentVolume; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false
Error from server (Invalid): error when applying patch:

{"metadata":{"annotations":{"kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration":"{"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"PersistentVolume","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"pd-profile-volume"},"spec":{"accessModes":["ReadOnlyMany"],"capacity":{"storage":"10Gi"},"local":{"path":"/home/alice/projects/devops/lab05/pingidentity-server-profiles/getting-started/pingdirectory"},"nodeAffinity":{"required":{"nodeSelectorTerms":[{"matchExpressions":[{"key":"kubernetes.io/hostname","operator":"In","values":["docker-desktop"]}]}]}},"storageClassName":"pd-local-in-storage","volumeMode":"Filesystem"}}\n"}},"spec":{"local":{"path":"/home/alice/projects/devops/lab05/pingidentity-server-profiles/getting-started/pingdirectory"}}}

to:
Resource: "/v1, Resource=persistentvolumes", GroupVersionKind: "/v1, Kind=PersistentVolume"
Name: "pd-profile-volume", Namespace: ""
for: "lab05-local-profile-deploy.yaml": PersistentVolume "pd-profile-volume" is invalid: spec.persistentvolumesource: Forbidden: is immutable after creation

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

The yaml file looks like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  PING_IDENTITY_ACCEPT_EULA: "YES"
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  labels:
    role: pingdirectory
  name: pingdirectory-environment-variables
---
apiVersion: v1
data:
  PING_IDENTITY_ACCEPT_EULA: "YES"
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  labels:
    role: pingfederate
  name: pingfederate-environment-variables
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    role: pingdataconsole
  name: pingdataconsole
spec:
  ports:
  - name: https
    port: 8443
  selector:
    role: pingdataconsole
  type: NodePort
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    role: pingdirectory
  name: pingdirectory
spec:
  ports:
  - name: ldaps
    port: 636
  - name: ssl
    port: 443
  - name: ldap
    port: 389
  selector:
    role: pingdirectory
  type: NodePort
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    role: pingfederate
  name: pingfederate
spec:
  ports:
  - name: pf-console
    port: 9999
  - name: pf-runtime
    port: 9031
  selector:
    role: pingfederate
  type: NodePort
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: pd-profile-volume
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadOnlyMany
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  local:
    path: /home/alice/projects/devops/lab05/pingidentity-server-profiles/getting-started/pingdirectory
  nodeAffinity:
    required:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
      - matchExpressions:
        - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
          operator: In
          values:
          - docker-desktop
  storageClassName: pd-local-in-storage
  volumeMode: Filesystem
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: pf-profile-volume
nodeAffinity:
  required:
    nodeSelectorTerms:
    - matchExpressions:
      - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
        operator: In
        values:
        - docker-desktop
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadOnlyMany
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  local:
    path: /home/alice/projects/devops/lab05/pingidentity-server-profiles/getting-started/pingfederate
  storageClassName: pf-local-in-storage
  volumeMode: Filesystem
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: pd-profile-claim
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadOnlyMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 10Gi
  storageClassName: pd-local-in-storage
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: pf-profile-claim
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadOnlyMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 10Gi
  storageClassName: pf-local-in-storage
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    role: pingdataconsole
  name: pingdataconsole
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      role: pingdataconsole
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        role: pingdataconsole
      name: pingdataconsole
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: pingidentity/pingdataconsole:edge
        name: pingdataconsole
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8443
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 200m
            memory: 1.5Gi
          requests:
            cpu: 200m
            memory: 1.5Gi
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    role: pingfederate
  name: pingfederate
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      role: pingfederate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        role: pingfederate
      name: pingfederate
    spec:
      containers:
      - envFrom:
        - configMapRef:
            name: pingfederate-environment-variables
        - secretRef:
            name: devops-secret
            optional: true
        image: pingidentity/pingfederate:edge
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        livenessProbe:
          failureThreshold: 1
          httpGet:
            path: /pingfederate/app
            port: 9999
            scheme: HTTPS
          initialDelaySeconds: 100
          periodSeconds: 1
        name: pingfederate
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9999
        - containerPort: 9031
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /pingfederate/app
            port: 9999
            scheme: HTTPS
          periodSeconds: 10
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: "1"
            memory: 1.5Gi
          requests:
            cpu: "1"
            memory: 1.5Gi
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /opt/in
          name: pf-profile-storage
      volumes:
      - name: pf-profile-storage
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: pf-profile-claim
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  labels:
    role: pingdirectory
  name: pingdirectory
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      role: pingdirectory
  serviceName: pingdirectory
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        role: pingdirectory
      name: pingdirectory
    spec:
      containers:
      - envFrom:
        - configMapRef:
            name: pingdirectory-environment-variables
        - secretRef:
            name: devops-secret
            optional: true
        image: pingidentity/pingdirectory:edge
        lifecycle:
          preStop:
            exec:
              command:
              - /bin/sh
              - -c
              - /preStop.sh
        livenessProbe:
          exec:
            command:
            - /bin/sh
            - -c
            - /opt/liveness.sh
          initialDelaySeconds: 300
          periodSeconds: 30
        name: pingdirectory
        ports:
        - containerPort: 636
        - containerPort: 443
        - containerPort: 389
        readinessProbe:
          exec:
            command:
            - /bin/sh
            - -c
            - /opt/liveness.sh
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: "2"
            memory: 2Gi
          requests:
            cpu: "2"
            memory: 2Gi
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /opt/in
          name: pd-profile-storage
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 300
      volumes:
      - name: pd-profile-storage
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: pd-profile-claim
```

Answer (score 0):

You might need to check what you have deployed previously. Do a kubectl get pv and pvc and check if there are any existing resources with the same name. If so delete them from your namespace and try deploying again.

Answer (score 0):

According to [k8s api reference](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.19/#persistentvolumespec-v1-core), `nodeAffinity` section have to be under `spec` field.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: pf-profile-volume
spec:
  nodeAffinity:       # <<< LOOK HERE >>>
    required:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
      - matchExpressions:
        - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
          operator: In
          values:
          - docker-desktop
  accessModes:
  - ReadOnlyMany
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  local:
    path: /home/alice/projects/devops/lab05/pingidentity-server-profiles/getting-started/pingfederate
  storageClassName: pf-local-in-storage
  volumeMode: Filesystem
```

---

You can also run:

```
kubectl explain pv.spec.nodeAffinity
```

to get field description.